# Dojo build ends up with warnings, but why?

Tags: javascript, build, dojo

I am new to dojo and I am trying to learn how to build an application with the utilities giving in dojo version 1.11.2. I raed this tutorial [Creating builds - Dojo Toolkit Tutorial](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/build/index.html) and try it by myself.

I have this structure:
[image: Structure of my project]

My app.profile.js looks like this:

```
var profile = (function(){
    return {
    basePath: "./src",
    releaseDir: "../../app",
    releaseName: "dev",
    action: "release",
    layerOptimize: "closure",
    optimize: "closure",
    cssOptimize: "comments",
    mini: true,
    stripConsole: "warn",
    selectorEngine: "lite",

    defaultConfig: {
        hasCache:{
            "dojo-built": 1,
            "dojo-loader": 1,
            "dom": 1,
            "host-browser": 1,
            "config-selectorEngine": "lite"
        },
        async: 1
    },

    staticHasFeatures: {
        "config-deferredInstrumentation": 0,
        "config-dojo-loader-catches": 0,
        "config-tlmSiblingOfDojo": 0,
        "dojo-amd-factory-scan": 0,
        "dojo-combo-api": 0,
        "dojo-config-api": 1,
        "dojo-config-require": 0,
        "dojo-debug-messages": 0,
        "dojo-dom-ready-api": 1,
        "dojo-firebug": 0,
        "dojo-guarantee-console": 1,
        "dojo-has-api": 1,
        "dojo-inject-api": 1,
        "dojo-loader": 1,
        "dojo-log-api": 0,
        "dojo-modulePaths": 0,
        "dojo-moduleUrl": 0,
        "dojo-publish-privates": 0,
        "dojo-requirejs-api": 0,
        "dojo-sniff": 1,
        "dojo-sync-loader": 0,
        "dojo-test-sniff": 0,
        "dojo-timeout-api": 0,
        "dojo-trace-api": 0,
        "dojo-undef-api": 0,
        "dojo-v1x-i18n-Api": 1,
        "dom": 1,
        "host-browser": 1,
        "extend-dojo": 1
    },

    packages:[{
        name: "dojo",
        location: "dojo"
    },{
        name: "dijit",
        location: "dijit"
    },{
        name: "dojox",
        location: "dojox"
    },{
        name: "app",
        location: "app"
    }],

    layers: {
        "dojo/dojo": {
            include: [ "dojo/dojo", "dojo/i18n", "dojo/domReady",
                "app/main", "app/run" ],
            customBase: true,
            boot: true
        },
        "app/Dialog": {
            include: [ "app/Dialog" ]
        }
    }
};
})();
```

My package.json has this content:

```
{
"name": "app",
"description": "carDealer",
"version": "1.0",
"keywords": ["JavaScript", "Dojo", "Toolkit", "DojoX"],
"maintainers": [{
    "name": "XY"
}],
"contributors": [{
    "name": "XY"
}],
"licenses": [{
    "type": "AFLv2.1",
    "url": "http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/browser/dojox/trunk/LICENSE#L43"
},{
    "type": "BSD",
    "url": "http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/browser/dojox/trunk/LICENSE#L13"
}],
"bugs": "https://github.com/example/issues",
"repositories": [{
    "type": "git",
    "url": "http://github.com/example.git",
    "path": "packages/app"
}],
"dependencies": {
    "dojo": "~1.10.4",
    "dijit": "~1.10.4",
    "dojox": "~1.10.4"
},
"main": "src",
"homepage": "http://not-set-yet.com/",
"dojoBuild": "app.profile.js"
}
```

Always I am trying to make a test build with the given build.bat in the Powershell of the windows OS, I get this failure messages and warnings:

[image]

Please if you have any advice, let me know. I hate this configuration things. Want to get started with hacking. Many thx in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: it looks like some how the directory got messed up, since the location is calling `theDirectoryEtc/carDealerBackend/src/src/dojox`, where you really need the src directory to be called once.

Comment: Yes, I know....but where can I change the path? I have searched everywhere but I cannot find the right position to change it in the myapp.profile.js or in other config files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `app.profile.js` is located in `carDealerBackend/src`. 
In the profile you define `basePath: "./src"`.
So it searches in `carDealerBackend/src/src`.

Try to change `basePath` to `"."`.